# How do I easily replace the last x bits from a byte with x bits from another?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to write a small steganography program but I'm struggling with the basics (bit manipulation).

Lets say I have a string variable

```
char s[];
```

And a 3-position byte array

```
byte arr[3];
```

Now, as an example, what I'd like to do here is, go through all s, byte by byte, and do the following:

- Get the first 3 bits of the current byte of s and use the to replace the last 3 bits of arr[0]
- Get the following 3 bits of the current byte of s and use the to replace the last 3 bits of arr[1]
- Get last 2 bits of the current byte of s and use the to replace the last 2 bits of arr[2]

What is the simplest way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i < ...; ++i) {
  const byte b = s[i];
  arr[0] = (arr[0] & ~7) | ((b >> 5) & 7);
  arr[1] = (arr[1] & ~7) | ((b >> 2) & 7);
  arr[2] = (arr[2] & ~3) | b & 3);
}
```